# PyQt6 adding image resource to QDocument

Tags: qtextedit, pyqt6, qtextdocument

I am porting an application from PyQT5 to PyQt6. It displays multiple images in a QTextEdit. I need to add an image resource to QTextEdit QTextDocument but am getting an error.

TypeError: addResource(self, int, QUrl, Any): argument 1 has unexpected type 'ResourceType'

Method variables are img: Dictionary, counter: Integer, text_edit: QTextEdit

```
path_ = self.app.project_path
if img['mediapath'][0] == "/":
    path_ = path_ + img['mediapath']
else:
     path_ = img['mediapath'][7:]
document = text_edit.document()
image = QtGui.QImageReader(path_).read()
image = image.copy(img['x1'], img['y1'], img['width'], img['height'])
# Need unique image names or the same image from the same path is reproduced
imagename = self.app.project_path + '/images/' + str(counter) + '-' + img['mediapath']
url = QtCore.QUrl(imagename)
document.addResource(QtGui.QTextDocument.ResourceType.ImageResource, url, QtCore.QVariant(image))
```

The Qt6 documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextdocument.html#addResource says:

For example, you can add an image as a resource in order to reference it from within the document:

```
document->addResource(QTextDocument::ImageResource,
    QUrl("mydata://image.png"), QVariant(image));
```

Note: I have tried the following which matches the Qt6 documentation:

```
document.addResource(QtGui.QTextDocument.ImageResource, url, QtCore.QVariant(image))
```

This gives the error: AttributeError: type object 'QTextDocument' has no attribute 'ImageResource'

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. What version of PyQt6 and Qt6 are you using? Have you tried to use `int(QtGui.QTextDocument.ResourceType.ImageResource)`?

Comment: I'm not on my Ubuntu dev computer right now. Currently on Windows 10 computer. Same error. using from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR, PYQT_VERSION_STR, both Qt and PyQT are 6.2.3

Comment: are you saying that using `document.addResource(int(QtGui.QTextDocument.ResourceType.ImageResource), url, QtCore.QVariant(image))` it still gives the *same exact* error? That seems strange. Also, you shouldn't need to use `QVariant`, I'm not yet that familiar with PyQt6, but since PyQt5 there shouldn't be any need for it (the type casting should be implied) and you should be able to use the QImage as argument.

Comment: yes regards the error. I know that using the QVariant worked before (Qt5) and works now (Qt6).  I will try without QVariant.

Comment: Tested now. You are correct, the QVariant method is not required.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works, and I think, either the QT6 documentation needs to be updated, or the PyQt6 implementation of the documentation needs to be developed.
The required Integer is stored in the value attribute:

```
document.addResource(QtGui.QTextDocument.ResourceType.ImageResource.value, url, QtCore.QVariant(image))
```

QVariant method is not required,  simpler code below:

```
document.addResource(QtGui.QTextDocument.ResourceType.ImageResource.value, url, image)
```

Comment: The PyQt documentation has been known to not be really comprehensive nor updated (mostly because 99.9% of the times it just matches the original C++ docs). Besides, this really seems to be a PyQT bug, not a Qt one, so I strongly suggest you to report it to the official [mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: OK I have sent riverbank an email.